# How to solve the issue that a Terminal screen is messed up? (usually after a resizing)

Tags: bash, terminal

Sometimes, a terminal screen is messed up, and when we use `man ls` to read the manpages, or press the UP arrow to go to previous commands in history, the screen will show characters not as the right place.  (for example, treat the end of screen as some where in the middle of the screen).

The command `reset` is tried and it wouldn't work.  One way that works is to log out or close the window, and resize the window first, and then do `ssh` (or close that tab, and resize the window, and then open a new tab to get a new shell).

But this way, we will lose anything that we previously did, such as starting a virtual machine console, etc.  So if we don't close the shell, is there a way to fix this problem?

(this happened before right inside Fedora, and also for a Macbook `ssh` into a RHEL 5.4 box).

**Update:** I remember now how it happened in Fedora: I opened up a Terminal, and did a FreeVM to use a console of a Virtual Machine (a shell).  I think it was size 80 x 25 and then after a while, I resized the Terminal to 130 x 50 approximately, and then the "inner shell" (of the VM) started to behave weird).

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Sounds broken if `reset` doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: whatever Terminal program inside of Fedora... and the default Terminal program on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: Please see update above for how it happened in Fedora

Comment: The magical incantation is `^Jreset^J`, where `^J` means pressing `ctrl-J`. Or (on graphical terminals) you can try the `Reset` button. Also, some programs just aren't prepared for terminal sizes changing underneath them (yes, ancient software is alive and kicking) or just misbehave badly when the terminal gets too small.

Comment: @vonbrand: after not finding that in *any* answer, I'd suggest you post it as one. This has helped me many times. Personally I found it on commandlinefoo.

Comment: My problems stemmed from bash miscalculating the length of the prompt because it had color codes in it; I was missing the escape characters \\[ and \\] - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly

Comment: I don't think this warrants an answer but... Instead of reset you can also try `echo -e \\033c`. I have also noticed that if you open up a curses program (e.g. vim) and then quit it restores the terminal. The former I got from the keyboard and console how-to a while ago and the latter I discovered on my own.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you are using bash, check if "checkwinsize" option is activated in your session using

```
shopt | grep checkwinsize
```

If you don't get

```
checkwinsize    on
```

then activate it with

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Bash documentation says for "checkwinsize" attribute :

> "If set, Bash checks the window size after each command and, if
>   necessary, updates the values of LINES and COLUMNS."

If you like the setting, you could activate `checkwinsize` in your `~/.bashrc`.

- To activate: `shopt -s checkwinsize`
- To deactivate: `shopt -u checkwinsize`

Comment: This doesn't happen to solve my problem, but this is a good general answer, so +1 anyway.  I think my problem relates to Windows emulation(?) when ssh-ing into a Linux server.

Comment: At first it seemed it didn't work when I used arrows up to see the history, but just after the first executed command it fixed everything. Using terminator in my case. Thanks +1

Comment: this worked for me, but only by turning *off* checkwinsize.  for some reason LINES=24 was being set after each command even though my window (containing a picocom session) was much taller.

Comment: `zsh: command not found: shopt` . ??

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson as stated, this is for bash, not zsh

Comment: @Arcadien . I actually found the solution . It was not `zsh`'s fault but my theme `powerlevel10k` that show some info on the right side. It was caused because of that . If anyone facing the same problem see [this](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/175)

Comment: By the way, `checkwinsize` is enabled by default in Bash 5

Comment: This doesn't work for `tmux` panes.

Answer (score 26):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. It clears and/or redraws the terminal screen, depending on the program.

Comment: but it doesn't permanently solve the problem...

Comment: I think I meant was, if you press CTRL L, then the line is ok for the moment, but if you edit the line again (or on the next command line you type), then the problem is still there

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem and none of the above recipes worked for me because I believe that my bash never receives the `SIGWINCH` signals, which are trapped by its parent process.

I finally found a solution. I added to my `.bashrc`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="resize &>/dev/null ; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Now every time I get a new prompt, my window is re-adjusted.

Thanks to [UKmonkey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/262316/ukmonkey) for the PROMPT_COMMAND improvement.

Comment: I personally would go with `export PROMPT_COMMAND="resize &>/dev/null; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` so that the old prompt command, whatever it my be will be preserved

Comment: I would just run resize manually when needed.  Interrogating the console for size can be slow.  Doing it every command seems excessive, and usually you know when it has been resized.

Answer (score 16):

I face same problem from time to time using zsh on macOS. A simple invocation of `reset` command sets up the terminal to my liking again.

Comment: So the OP mentioned that `reset` was not working for them, and this was in fact the point of the question....

Comment: OP has mentioned about it not working on Linux flavours. I faced the issue on MacOS Sierra and `reset` worked in this case. I added this answer to help anyone, who faces same problem on a MacOS and is not aware about `reset` command.

Comment: `reset` works on Windows Putty with Ubuntu 16.04!

Comment: reset worked on ubuntu 16.04 zsh

Comment: Yes this is one way of doing it. And if not `echo -e \\033c` is another option.

Comment: reset didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04 running Byobu. echo -e \\033c worked. @Pryftan how does this work?

Comment: If using zsh, then `ttyctl -f` will help with automatically applying a reset when you return to a prompt.

Answer (score 15):

adding these options to docker exec seemed to solve my problem

```
-e COLUMNS=$COLUMNS -e LINES=$LINES -e TERM=$TERM
```

Comment: were you the one who asked the question 5 years ago ?

Comment: I can tell you he's not: "docker" doesn't really fit with "5 years ago". Docker wasn't yet released in january 2013 ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add to what Arcadien had already mentioned. The checkwinsize enabling does the trick, but for me, what was needed was to reset the size of the window for it to work properly. I guess the checkwinsize was meant to eliminate this, but still, worth a shot. Just try changing the size of the window or un-maximizing and maximizing it post this option.

Comment: Believe it or not, this was all it took for mine to be fixed. Funny because I tried everything else first.

Answer (score 6):

Try `stty sane`. it should do what you need.

Comment: This is helpful some of the time true. It sometimes doesn't help all the situation though. It will incidentally turn on echo as if you did `stty echo`.

Comment: This messes up keybindings of the `emcs`

Answer (score 5):

if you are using `expect`

add this to the beginning of your script will work

```
#let pty slave device aware of WINCH signal
trap {
 set rows [stty rows]
 set cols [stty columns]
 stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
} WINCH
```

more details and explanations at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668254/109036

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's a common problem and there should be a simple solution.

If other measures like Ctrl + A Ctrl + L don't work, try using `stty`:

1. Ctrl + T: Open a new tab with a local shell.
   Or: Leave screen (Ctrl + A D to detach) and log out of your SSH session.
2. `stty -a | grep rows`: Get the number of rows and columns.
   Example: `speed 38400 baud; rows 33; columns 133; line = 0;`
3. Go back to your remote tab or log in and reattach screen. The `stty` output should be different.
   Example: `speed 38400 baud; rows 47; columns 177; line = 0;`
4. Type in `stty rows N` and `stty columns N` where N is the "real" number (outside of screen).
   Example: `$ stty rows 33; stty columns 133`

If you use **Terminator**, you can skip the first three steps because it shows the number of columns and rows at the top.

You don't have to resize your terminal windows to run into this. Admins usually log in from different computers and when the attached monitors differ in size (resolution), a window that's maximized will have a different size on each computer. It's actually rather difficult *not* to run into this frequently.

And the result isn't just that some man pages aren't showing up properly. It's pretty much anything that uses a pager - the first few lines are often missing (for example). And don't even think about using VIM in such a misaligned terminal. You want to highlight line 3 (V) in order to replace it, but when you do, the highlighted text is that of another line.

Comment: CentOS doesn't seem to have resize - use "stty rows 66" to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks man! I had a nasty issue with any ncruses programs used in gnu-screen. Your trick with stty rows 33; stty columns 133 solved my issue!.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and this is what I did:
I have a `.profile` setup in my user, so that is where I do all my changes.

There is a package called `xterm` which is available through `apt-get` I don't know about `yum`. But I did a local install from source as I do not have installation privileges. LINK: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/#download

```
./configure --prefix=/the/path/you/want/to/install/to
make
make install
```

I exported the path in my profile and invoked it at the same place

```
export PATH=$PATH:/the/path/you/want/to/install/to
resize
```

So now every time I log in, the terminal size is set accordingly by resize.

Answer (score 2):

Run **`resize`** after resizing your terminal window. It will update `COLUMNS` and `ROWS` to the correct values.

Comment: This is a good answer, and the only one that worked for me, using `less` in a remote SSH console.