# xterm resizing causes shell to mess up

Tags: ksh, xterm

I'm using reflection x, which uses xterm as the terminal emulator.  If I maximize and minimize the window several times, when I try to access previous commands, the text becomes messed up.  The issue is very similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res), however, I'm using the ksh shell instead of bash.  So what would the ksh version of the solution be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually need to make use of the `resize` and `reset` commands to sometimes clear/fix problems when resizing the actual xterm window.

To use `resize`:

```
$ eval `resize`
```

If you run `resize` by itself, it'll report what the columns & lines will be set to.

To use `reset`:

```
$ reset
```

#### References

- [reset man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset)
- [resize man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/resize)

Answer (score 1):

The `reset` command won't help with cleanup from resizing.

The `resize` command can be helpful, but there is a pitfall.  There are two main use-cases for `resize`:

- telling the system how large the screen is when it cannot tell, e.g., connecting through a serial interface with no NAWS (negotiations about window size) support.  This is useful for FAQs.
- repairing the environment variables needlessly set through previous use of `resize`.  This one produces bug reports.

The `resize` program was originally written when termcap-based systems were common.  A typical termcap description tells how large the screen is, because most of the termcap applications written back in the 1980s did not include the system calls to ask how large the screen actually was.  That started changing in the late 1980s with the introduction of the `SIGWINCH` signal and system calls to obtain the information.

However, due to these legacy applications, a convention was established that said that (by default) if the `LINES` and/or `COLUMNS` variables were set, then those would override the termcap description.

So far, so good.

However, some applications (including shells such as bash which is essentially a termcap application) will pay more attention to these `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables than the actual screensize.

If you *evaluate* the output of `resize`, you will set those variables.  That seems fine, until (you may notice) on resizing the window again, the programs that were following screensize changes are no longer doing so.

No problem, you just repeat what you did with `resize`.

On the other hand, if you simply run `resize` *without* evaluating its output, it updates the system's notion of the screensize.

Further reading:

- [**`resize`**  - *set environment and terminal settings to current xterm window size*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html)
- [**`tset`**, **`reset`** - *terminal initialization*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html)
- [use_env](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env), a library function allowing the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` to be ignored.
- [Handling SIGWINCH (resize events)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#handle_resize)