# Hard-set (NOT resize/reset) stty rows/columns in ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, grub.cfg?

Tags: putty, stty

When I PuTTy in, I typically: "stty rows 48 columns 240" after login.

- I'm after a single-line/entry, in .profile or .bashrc or even grub.cfg to hard-set stty cols/rows
- If this requires a script, I can work with the links below.
- If there's a direct solution I'd like to find it.

Addendum

- Xterm is not installed
- PuTTy connection is into Host
- Virsh console is then used to connect to VM
- Looking to set/adjust the rows/cols on the VM when I log in with my profile
- When I connect, my "PuTTy->Window->Size->Columns/Rows" are preset to the values I'm after. This setting does not resize the VM's Col/Row size.
- Hence the need for "stty rows 48 columns 240" after login <- which I am trying to eliminate

Resize/reset discussed at great length:

- [How to solve the issue that a Terminal screen is messed up? (usually after a resizing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res)
- [resizable serial console window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/resizable-serial-console-window/283206)
- http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/serial

Comment: The question does not explain what is wrong with using the command that is in the very first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `resize` program can do this for you:

> **`resize -s`** *rows* *cols*

or for your example

```
resize -s 48 240
```

This is a feature of xterm which PuTTY happens to recognize (it can be disabled in the *`Terminal / Features`* menu, but is normally enabled).

There's a possible terminfo capability which could be set up, but it is used unconditionally by GNU screen and would be a nuisance.  So we don't add that capability to the terminal description.

The feature used is documented in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps;Ps;Ps-t:Ps-=-8;height;width.2519):

> *`CSI`* *Ps* ; *Ps* ; *Ps* **`t`**
>
> Window manipulation (XTWINOPS), **`dtterm`**, extended by **`xterm`**.
> These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
> resource.

The first *Ps* is here:

> *Ps* = **`8`** **`;`**  *height* **`;`**  *width* ⇒  Resize the text area to given
> height and width in characters.  Omitted parameters reuse the
> current height or width.  Zero parameters use the display's
> *height* or *width*.

Some of the background for the window-manipulation feature is documented in the [*Miscellaneous*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Miscellaneous) section.

For your example, you could hardcode it like this:

```
printf '\033[8;%d;%dt' $height $width
```

Whether you are using `resize` or just a `printf`, PuTTY will resize its window, sending a `SIGWINCH` via the connection which will update the terminal's size—just as if you had issued a `stty` command.

However... if you're using a *serial line*, that `SIGWINCH` goes nowhere.  `resize` is unaffected, since it is designed to handle this case.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Thomas. I'm trying to hard-set/configure these values in a scenario where xterm is not installed.  Where.. the cols/rows need to be redefined... but redefined to predetermined values, not the actual screen size.

Comment: Could you add that to your question? It's valuable context to help with finding an answer for you, @Gus

Comment: If OP needs stty settings that don't match the actual screensize, that would be a rather unusual case.

Comment: Addendum added. I don't want or need the end machine to query my window size. I have my window size pre-configured in PuTTy and it's the only PC I connect from. I want the VM to recognize, that when it's me logging in, I want a predefined col/row setting to be used.