# How to solve the issue that a remote Terminal screen is messed up when using `expect`? (usually after a resizing)

Tags: shell, ssh, remote, expect

Using `expect` and password auto-login to remote with ssh, when resizing the window, `stty size` report old size. Cause commands like `vim` and `less` mess up.

Answer (score 7):

after a long time of search and test, finally find out it's `expect` that cause the issue, by default expect will not forward WINCH signal, this can fix by trap command like this

```
trap {
 #fetch rows and cols from controlling terminal
 #note  [] is tcl way of call and here the stty is expect's not system's which not support "stty rows" to query rows
 set rows [stty rows]
 set cols [stty columns]
 #send "echo size changed to $rows $cols\r"
 #according to the man page, the variable spawn_out(slave,name) is set to the name of the pty slave device
 stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
} WINCH
```

after add this at begining of my expect file, every thing works fine.

thanks Anish Sneh from https://askubuntu.com/a/672919/1384831

want to answer at [How to solve the issue that a Terminal screen is messed up? (usually after a resizing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res) but it is protected, so post a new question. wish it will save some others time.

Comment: Your issue and your answer are specific to `expect`. The other question does not mention `expect` at all. IMO in such case asking a separate question is justified.

Comment: many people (at least me) don't realize it's expect's problem, that question is so hot and is the first search result of "remote shell resize issue" from google. I have tried all answers there without any luck and almost give up. recently, in some cases, I use `ssh` directly without `expect` and finally realize it's expect's issue.