# Chaotic Command-line Interface Layout

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, input

When I type a long command on a command-line interface. Something strange may happen in the layout. The characters I typed don't show in lines correctly. Instead, they merge into 1 line or overwrite each other. And the cursor isn't displayed in its right place. For example:
I want to type:

```
/home/user/example/a/b/c>$ tar --create --file example.tar e  
xample
```

But it shows:

```
xampleuser/example/a/b/c>$ tar --create --file example.tar e
```

As shown above, the second line overwrite the first line.
This problem happens in Linux on different computers. I've met similiar problems both in tty and GUI terminal emulator.
It's only a problem in the display, because what I type is exactly what I enter, although it may not be what is shown.
I use American keyboard. The encoding and keymap settings are all the default ones. The keyboard is fine.
More details:

- font: terminus-132n(tty), terminus 24pt(GUI terminal emulator)
- OS: Linux 5.18.15-arch1-1
- `$LANG`: en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the issue that a Terminal screen is messed up? (usually after a resizing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res)

Comment: @don_aman's tip could be helpful, especially if you're using terminals with odd font sizes and window geometry.

Comment: What shell are you using? Does this still happen when changing the shell?

Comment: Possibly related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Enter this command:

```
export PS1="$PWD>"
```

Then try a long command and see if the behavior changes.  If it does, there's most likely a problem with the PS1 definition in your profile.  When customizing PS1 try not to get too fancy, and avoid special characters and control codes if at all possible.

Comment: If it's `bash`, they most likely forgot to put non-printing characters between `\[` and `\]`.  Or, they put escape-sequences anywhere but within `%{ ... %}` in the `zsh` shell's prompt.

Comment: Agreed, but to determine that, my suggestion is to make PS1 very simple and see if the behavior changes.